# when i publish asp.net mvc i got error Could not load file or assembly 'App_Browsers - Copy' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Any thoughts on what might be causing this exception?
**when i publish asp.net mvc project  i got following error**

"Could not load file or assembly 'App_Browsers - Copy' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040

i cannot use application i develop for one year ,
i have tried google search but no one talk about it
please can u help me to solve this Error?

Comment: Permanent delete the `bin` folder and then `rebuild` the solution again.

Answer (score 0):

Check IIS If you have enabled 32 bit application also

Go to IIS -> Application Pool -> Advance Settings -> Enable 32-bit Applications

try remcompile an then redeployment

Answer (score 0):

i finally find solution by following steps:
1-I update packages on nuget
2-publish to new folder